# Convert Puppeteers HttpResponse.timing().requestTime to real time

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using puppeteers [page.on('requestFinished')](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.7.0&show=api-event-requestfinished) event in my web scraper. Part of the project, I need to collect each request start time and the time it took to complete the request. I found [httpResponse.timing()](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v13.7.0&show=api-httpresponsetiming) but I couldn't wrap my head around the `requestTime` fields value. It looks like it is in seconds with decimal place, but, it neither an epoch time nor it is the time elapsed since I start my crawler process (monotonic time). What time format is it? Can we convert it to human understandable time, so that I know when the request started?

Example of `timing()` output:

```
{
  requestTime: 700151.9155,
  proxyStart: -1,
  proxyEnd: -1,
  dnsStart: 1.646,
  dnsEnd: 108.539,
  connectStart: 108.539,
  connectEnd: 218.554,
  sslStart: 164.675,
  sslEnd: 218.531,
  workerStart: -1,
  workerReady: -1,
  workerFetchStart: -1,
  workerRespondWithSettled: -1,
  sendStart: 221.102,
  sendEnd: 222.261,
  pushStart: 0,
  pushEnd: 0,
  receiveHeadersEnd: 364.526
}
{
  requestTime: 700152.313434,
  proxyStart: -1,
  proxyEnd: -1,
  dnsStart: -1,
  dnsEnd: -1,
  connectStart: -1,
  connectEnd: -1,
  sslStart: -1,
  sslEnd: -1,
  workerStart: -1,
  workerReady: -1,
  workerFetchStart: -1,
  workerRespondWithSettled: -1,
  sendStart: 1.316,
  sendEnd: 2.29,
  pushStart: 700152.24554,
  pushEnd: 700152.24558,
  receiveHeadersEnd: 13.923
}
```

Comment: Makes no sense to me neither. I suggest you to create an issue on the puppeteer Github repo OR to try to do your thing using `perfromance` Object in the browser directly.. That object also holds metrics about requests. Alternatively you could calculate the effectiv request length using the `timing()` API and use the time a `request` event is fired as start time. Depending on how exact the start point has to be ^^

Comment: same here, no clue what these times mean.